# How can I search by relationship in Contact.get?

Tags: api, relationships

Is there a way to search by relationship in the Contact.get API call?

Eg: give me all the contacts that are individuals, in group 9 and have a relationship type 8 (optionally specifying direction and/or the other contact) ?

I'm modifying existing code that builds a variety of filters into a Contact.get call and I want to add relationships to that.

The new join feature in 4.7 looks hopeful except that it is not advertised for Contacts in the API explorer.

Comment: Correct, the Contact api unfortunately uses a legacy query builder that prevents it from supporting joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to require a second api call, first to retrieve a list of relationships for the 2nd contact, use a php loop to turn the list of relations into an array, and then you can add that to the original api call like

`'id' => array('IN', $related_contact_ids)`

PS. I'm not sure if the contact api3 supports this syntax.